# Typecasting to NSMutableDictionary returns nil

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

```
NSObject *ob //this object has some value
let scoreMap:NSMutableDictionary? = ob as? NSMutableDictionary // the scoreMap is populated with nil value
```

However, if I modify the above statement to

```
let scoreMap:NSDictionary? = ob as? NSDictionary
```

I get the desired value in scoreMap. Any pointers why is this the behavior difference between Dictionary & NSDictionary?

Answer (score 1):

`NSDictionary` and `NSMutableDictionary` are two different classes. `NSMutableDictionary` inherits from `NSDictionary`. While you can cast an `NSMutableDictionary` to an `NSDictionary`, you can't cast an `NSDictionary` to an `NSMutableDictionary`.

If you have an `NSDictionary` and you want to get an `NSMutableDictionary`, you need to call `mutableCopy` on the `NSDictionary`.

But this is Swift. Don't use either of these classes at all. Use a Swift dictionary. Use `var` or `let` to indicate whether the dictionary is mutable or not.